# Как проксировать в nginx и подставить в адрес get запрос?

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass

**ЗАДАЧА.** В адресной строке браузера ввожу proxy.localhost/godzilla (proxy.localhost мой виртальный хост). Nginx проксирует этот запрос, после чего в адресной строке дожно остаться proxy.localhost/godzilla но по факту дожно перейти на https://rezka.ag/search/?do=search&subaction=search&q=godzilla

Мой код:

```
server {
<------>listen *:80;
<------>server_name proxy.localhost;
<------>location /(.*) {
<------><------>    proxy_pass https://rezka.ag/search/?do=search&subaction=search&q=$1;
<------><------>    proxy_set_header Host rezka.ag;
<------>}
}
```

**Пожалуйста помогите**, а то уже всё перепробовал.

P.S. У меня выдаёт 403 ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прокси на примере ru.stackoverflow.com

```
server {
    server_name my.host.name;
    listen 80;

    default_type    text/html;


    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Host                'ru.stackoverflow.com';
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-for     $remote_addr;

    proxy_connect_timeout   120;
    proxy_send_timeout      120;
    proxy_read_timeout      120;
    client_max_body_size    50m;

    sub_filter  'https:'    'http:';
    sub_filter  '/ru.stackoverflow.com'     '/my.host.name';
    sub_filter  '/stackoverflow.com'        '/my.host.name';
    sub_filter_once off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          https://ru.stackoverflow.com;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding "";
    }
    location ~ ^/(.+)$ {
        proxy_pass          https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=$1;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding "";
    }
}
```

Проверено на `nginx version: nginx/1.19.10`

Comment: И как реализовать в вашем примере чтобы вводили в адресную строку my.host.name/test1 а по факту переходило в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=test1, но в браузерной строке оставалось my.host.name/test1?

Comment: а как в вашем подходе отличить когда прокси должен переходить на страницу, а когда интерпретировать url как поисковый запрос? "my.host.name/questions" и "my.host.name/questions/1281500" ничем не отличаются от "my.host.name/test1"

Comment: Я новичёк в nginx и могли бы вы пожалуйста помочь и показать на вашем примере (подходе) как передать поисковый запрос, который указан после виртуального хоста и слеша (например my.host.name/поисковый_запрос) вот сюда ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=поисковый_запрос ?

Comment: я, наверное, могу выдумать такой ЧПУ для nginx. но, смотрите, с адреса "my.host.name/поисковый_запрос" вы получили список найденных страниц. каждая найденная страница это - урл вида "my.host.name/questions/1281500". каждый такой урл будет интерпретирован ЧПУ как "поисковый_запрос" и при клике вы перейдёте на страницу поиска с поисковым запросом "questions/1281500"

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста кодом, если не сложно.

Comment: добавил________

Comment: Спасибо, к сожалению конкретно на вашем примере не работает выдаёт ошибку: "Не удается получить доступ к сайту Проверьте, нет ли опечаток в имени хоста my.host.name. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN". P.S. Проверил, опечаток нет. Но это может быть проблема со стороны stackoverflow. Ваш код у вас работает? =) Подставил ваш шаблон под свои данные, работает, только во время поиска сам сайт не всё подгружает, но поиск выполняет. Спасибо большое, добра вам и счастья =)